# Ignore duplicates in FOREACH function / PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a php solution to make sure the @mail doesn't process any duplicate email addresses.

```html
$get_partner_emails = "SELECT email_address FROM partners WHERE partner_id ='$partner_id' AND active ='yes'";
                
if ($email_addresses = $connect->query($get_partner_emails)) {
  foreach ($email_addresses as $email_address) {
    $email_address = $email_address['email_address'];
    @mail($email_address, $partner_subject, $partner_message, $partner_headers);
  }
} else {
  echo "Error: No Partner Email Addresses Found<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to filter the adresses like so :

```
<?php 

$get_partner_emails = "SELECT email_address FROM partners WHERE partner_id ='$partner_id' AND active ='yes'";

$adresses = array();

if ($email_addresses = $connect->query($get_partner_emails)) {
  foreach ($email_addresses as $email_address) {
    $adresses[$email_address['email_address']] = true;
  }
  foreach ($adresses as $adress => $true) {
    @mail($adress, $partner_subject, $partner_message, $partner_headers);
  }
} else {
  echo "Error: No Partner Email Addresses Found<br>";
}
```

If you accept to filter the adresses with MySQL, add `DISTINCT` in the query, it will remove the duplicates, with nothing more to change :

```
<?php 

$get_partner_emails = "SELECT DISTINCT email_address FROM partners WHERE partner_id ='$partner_id' AND active ='yes'";

if ($email_addresses = $connect->query($get_partner_emails)) {
  foreach ($email_addresses as $email_address) {
    $email_address = $email_address['email_address'];
    @mail($email_address, $partner_subject, $partner_message, $partner_headers);
  }
} else {
  echo "Error: No Partner Email Addresses Found<br>";
}
```

Comment: Even though my answer does solve the problem, I like this DISTINCT version more. No extra iterations. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the sent addresses in a "cache" array like so:

```
$handled = array();
foreach ($email_addresses as $address) {
    $email_address = $address['email_address'];
    if(isset($handled[$email_address ])) {
        // Already handled address
        continue;
    }
    @mail($email_address , $partner_subject, $partner_message, $partner_headers);
    $handled[$email_address ] = true;
}
```

...if this is what you ment.